# Making a function the variable of another

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I've created a function `grid(n)` on Python (using networkx) which returns a simple graph with "n" nodes. I'm now trying to create another function called "edge". I want "edge" to accept `grid(n)` as an argument and I want to make use of the "n" (in grid(n)) in the body of the edge function. Is this possible?

I've tried:

```
def edge(grid(n)):
"function body"
```

But it's giving me an invalid syntax error?

Any help would be much appreciated,

Jack

Comment: was my explanation helpful ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Not Possible !!!**

while defining a method, only the parameter names (not the values) will be mentioned. So a typical method definition would be like:

```
def fun(param1,param2,...):
```

*Note that you can always mention the default values for the parameters.*

when you write: `def edge(grid(n)):` , grid(n) method will execute first and then it will return some object but you are supposed to provide the parameter names while defining the method.

**Alternate:**

You can define the edge method like this:

```
def edge(grid,n):
   g = grid(n)
   #do rest of the stuff here !!!!
```

In the code above, you are passing grid method as the first argument and then n as the second argument. You can always call grid method inside edge method as shown.

Answer (score 1):

If you call `edge(grid(n))`, then `edge` will be called with `grid(n)`.  What is `grid(n)`?  Apparently it's a simple graph with `n` nodes.  So it will respond with the same as if you did

```
G = grid(n)
edge(G)
```

You can do things like

```
def edge(fxn, argument):
    G = fxn(argument)
    print G.edges()[0]
edge(grid,n)
```

to send a function as an argument to another function.  It's not clear to me from your question if this does what you're wanting to do.

Answer (score 0):

When you define a function you should specify just parameter:

```
def edge(graph):
    pass
```

and when you call function, you'll pass parameter into it:

```
edge(grid(n))
```

or you could write edge function that depends on "n" parameter:

```
def edge(n):
    graph = grid(n)
    #using graph variable
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to use value `n` for both function, you can try like this :

```
def grid(n):
    """
    Function Body
    """

def edge(n):
    """
    Function Body
    """

def main():
    n = 2
    grid(n)
    edge(n)

main()
```